# Partitioning a 1 TB SSD for Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in a dual boot configuration with Windows 11 Pro on a newly built system with 2 separate 1 TB NVME SSDs (nvme0 and nvme1). Windows 11 is installed on nvme0 (in UEFI boot mode) and I am planning to install Ubuntu on nvme1. I have selected custom install. Given my configuration what is a good useable recommendation for partitions and sizes for nvme1? There is an EFI partition that shows up on nvme0 - do I need to manually create a separate EFI partition on nvme1 or will that naturally occur during installation? Thanks.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug. There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments.  You don't need to put an efi partition on the second internal disk, but I like that approach, and you can set it up yourself with a partitioning tool before installation. (then fix it up afterwards).

Comment: "Given my configuration what is a good useable recommendation for partitions and sizes for nvme1?" depends largely on how you want to use W11 and Ubuntu. And as such it is personal. Generally I would suggest to divide the OS and personal files and make a guess to how much personal files you expect to need (do you want to keep BD video files for movies you watched?). And if you want personal files to be used on both use a filesystem both support.